Rav Moshe Feinstein's advice on doing teshuvah
In the sefer Igros Uksavim (Vol. 1, p. 25, letter 25), by Rabbi Wolbe, he quotes Rav Moshe Feinstein (בכרך י' סי' קטו בחלק אורח חיים) and says:

There is a response from the great Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, of blessed memory, to someone who struggled with this, where he offers various pieces of advice and concludes his letter by saying, "I conclude that your repentance will be complete, and you will grow in Torah and fear of Heaven."

Does anyone know where to find the original text from the Igros Moshe and what it says?

The translation missed a critical point. In the responsum below, Rabbi Feinstein didn't say "your repentance will be complete"; he said "I bless you that your repentance will be complete." That's not the same degree of certainty. But he has several similar responsa, including one where a woman is clearly beating herself up years after something she'd done, and it's taking the toll on her whole family.

@Shalom interesting, thanks. Can you maybe provide a correct translation to the piece below in the answer? Also, where can I find that responsa on the case with the woman?

Rabbi Feinstein has several responsa in a row on similar topics. From OC4:115 to OC4:118; follow the link below and keep reading.

The woman's case is 117; whatever she did was long ago, would never happen again, and not of halachic import. It appears her husband wrote to Rav Moshe because she couldn't get over it.

It concludes: "She must also know that G-d forbid for her to be depressed, rather joyous that she has merited to repentance and a husband who is a Torah scholar; and on this Yom Kippur, Hashem will grant her complete atonement. And may Hashem bless her and her husband with everything good, peace, tranquility, and delight from G-d-blessed children for all generations. Blessing her with love and happiness, Moshe Feinstein"

The original text is from Igros Moshe (Vol 6; OC 4, Siman 115). Here is a snapshot of the title of the teshuva.

This is the passage you cited:


Wonderful, Thank you. Could you provide the english translation of it perhaps?

@Shmuel The main passage: And the best advice is to learn Torah in depth, because it rescues and protects from all matters of arayot, and even from hirhurim, as Rambam taught at the end of the laws of forbidden relations. They gave even greater advice (Kiddushin 30b): 'a person should turn himself, and his thoughts to divrei Torah, and expand his mind and wisdom', and even more importantly, this will effectively save from the yeitzer hara of this disgraceful sin. And I conclude with a blessing that your repentance be complete and perfect, and that you grow in Torah and fear of Hashem

Note quite "I conclude that your repentance will be complete." I thought it was an odd expression.
